# jooQ 3.13 insert batch with change one column

Tags: java, spring, jooq

I have table Car in two DB. Car in first table has column details as TEXT, in second has column details as JSONB. But I have only one generated class with TEXT field. How can I do **batch insert** into table 2 using generated class Car and I need to change field from TEXT to JSONB.
I insert into table with `dsl.batchInsert(records).execute();`

And its my field in jooq generated class

```
public final TableField<Car, String> DETAILS = createField("details", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.TExT.nullable(false).defaultValue(org.jooq.impl.DSL.field("", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.TEXT)), this, "");
```

I need insert into second table smth like `dsl.batchInsert(changeTextToJsonB(records)).execute();` or smth else

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far? Any code examples we can use in order to better understand your setup might be helpful.

Comment: Added into main question

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is to generate two sets of classes, one for each DB, but I'm assuming this doesn't work for you.

You could then implement a [custom data type binding](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings/) and attach that to your column using the code generator. Your binding could read some context variable, e.g. from a `ThreadLocal` for a quick and dirty solution, or from your `Configuration.data()` map to decide whether it wants to delegate to the `VARCHAR` binding or to the `JSONB` binding.

```java
public class TextOrJsonBinding implements Binding<String, String> {

    @Override
    public void set(BindingSetStatementContext<U> ctx) throws SQLException {
        var db = ctx.configuration().data("my-db");

        if ("db1".equals(db))
            SQLDataType.VARCHAR.getBinding().set(ctx);
        else if ("db2".equals(db))
            SQLDataType.JSONB.getBinding().set(ctx);
        else
            throw new DataAccessException("Unsupported DB: " + db);
    }

    // Repeat for all methods
}
```

With the above approach, you can now have two configurations for each DB (you probably already do, because you probably have different `DataSource` instances):

```java
Configuration db1 = new DefaultConfiguration();
db1.data("my-db", "db1");

Configuration db2 = new DefaultConfiguration();
db2.data("my-db", "db2");

// Produces VARCHAR bindings
db1.dsl().batchInsert(records).execute();

// Produces JSONB bindings
db2.dsl().batchInsert(records).execute();
```